# mpi_send will be blocked when it sends the second message

Tags: mpi

The node00 can send the information to node01 whose rank is 1 sucessfully, but it will be blocked on the second send to the node01. Why did it happen? Thanks a lot. I think there is no deadlock in the code.

Given the MPI programming, there are 5 nodes

```
.....
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
MPI_Status status;

int buff;

if(rank ==0)
{  
    buff=123;
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
    MPI_Send(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  //succeed
    MPI_Send(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  //blocked
   }
}
else
{
   MPI_Recv(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);//succeed
   MPI_Recv(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);//blocked
}
............
```

Comment: How did you determine that the call blocks? Is `tag` well defined and identical for each rank?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv.These are non blocking calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<mpi.h>
#define tag 777
int rank;
int size;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{


  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
//MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
MPI_Status status;

int buff;
int i;
if(rank ==0)
{  printf("hai");
    buff=123;
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
    MPI_Send(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  //succeed
    MPI_Send(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  //blocked
   }
}
else
{
printf("hello");
   MPI_Recv(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);//succeed
   MPI_Recv(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);//blocked
}

//MPI_Finalize(); //finalize MPI operations
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use mpi_finialize, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    int buff, tag = 99;
    MPI_Status status;
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        buff = 123;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            MPI_Send(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //succeed
            MPI_Send(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //blocked
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Recv(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //succeed
        printf("%d\n", buff);
        MPI_Recv(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); //blocked
        printf("%d\n", buff);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```